# Detection Idiom and SFINAE via Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I can use `std::experimental::is_detected` to check whether `chips1_t` can be instantiated with `float*` (which it can't) as shown in the `static_assert` below:

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename = void>
  struct chips1;

template <typename T>
struct chips1<T*,std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value>> {
  using type = int;
};

template <typename T> using chips1_t = typename chips1<T>::type;

static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected<chips1_t,float*>::value,"");
```

If I then try a check using `chips2_t`, a similar `static_assert`, shown below, will produce a compilation error; regarding the missing `type` member. Can anyone tell me why?

```
struct Base {};

template <typename>
  struct chips2;

template <typename T>
struct chips2<T*> : std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value,Base> {
  using type = int;
};

template <typename T> using chips2_t = typename chips2<T>::type;

static_assert(!std::experimental::is_detected<chips2_t,float*>::value,"");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, the base class is not part of the template type, so it's not considered during SFINAE (It's a *dependent base class*)

Instantiating

```
template <typename T>
struct chips2<T*>
```

Succeeds, and then compilation fails because it derives from `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value,Base>` which becomes an ill-formed expression.

---

You cannot specialize templates by their base class<sup>*</sup>.

For example, you couldn't have two competing specializations like:

```
template <typename T>
struct chips2<T*> : std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value,Base> {
  using type = int;
};

template <typename T>
struct chips2<T*> : std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T,int>::value,Base> {
  using type = float;
};
```

They would be considered identical from a specialization standpoint (i.e., they are identical from a naming standpoint, so the compiler will consider the second one to be a redeclaration of the first one). The only part that matters is everything up to the colon `:`

In the first case, your `enable_if` is directly part of the template specialization, so SFINAE works properly.

---

### Another note

In the second one, you've effectively made it impossible to instantiate `chips2` with anything other than `int*`, see the following example:

```
struct Base {};

template <typename>
struct chips2
{};

template <typename T>
struct chips2<T*> 
   : std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value, Base> 
{};

int main(){
    chips2<float*> c;
}
```

You might be inclined to think that SFINAE will choose the base class template for `c`, but in reality it chooses the specialization `chips2<T*>` because of what I said above, and compilation fails.

---

<sup>*</sup>Relevant standardese at [temp.spec]

> the name of the class that is explicitly specialized shall be a *simple-template-id.*

Where a *simple-template-id* is of the form: 
   *template-name < template-argument-listopt >*

e.g. `chips2<T*>`. Note that there is no option to also include the class it derives from